# FileNotFoundError with Python CDLL

Tags: python, c, dll

I have been struggling with this problem for several days. Basically, what I would like to do is to call a shared dll library using python. I created the dll using mingw32-make and the makefile is as follows:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-shared -fopenmp -L./
LIBS=-lpthread libopenblas.a
OPTIM=-O3
CURRENT_PATH=$(shell cd)
INITMODEL=$(CURRENT_PATH)/c_call/init_model.c
SRC=$(INITMODEL)
DEST=offline.dll

$(DEST): $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTIM) -o $(DEST) $(SRC) $(LIBS)
```

The compilation worked through but when I called the dll using python, I got an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\zhenh\Desktop\RTLoc\client\src\offline.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Then, I found python CDLL managed to load the dll when I remove linking "libopenblas.a" from the compilation. So I guess the problem may be due to that I did not compile openblas right. So I went to msys2 MinGW 32bit and compiled the openblas with mingw32-make, which it is for native windows. But when I put the newly compiled libopenblas.a in the makefile, CDLL gave the error again.

I also tried to link libopenblas.dll and failed. And openblas is the library I need to use so there are no ways to get rid of it.

The Python version is 3.8.7 and I have used os.add_dll_directory to include the folder having the dll I generated. Thanks everyone for giving me some idea how to fix this?

Comment: `-o3` means **write output to file named `3`**. You meant `-O3` with **capital `O`**

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes, I got that corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I switched to Anaconda Powershell Prompt.